# How to install nethack-qt in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, package-management

[Looks like this package should be available](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/nethack-qt), but `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nethack-qt` just reports that

> Package nethack-qt is not available, but is referred to by another package.

What gives?

Ubuntu Software Center reports that

> No items match "nethack-qt"

In software sources I've enabled everything in the Ubuntu Software tab and "Canonical Partners" in the Other Software tab. Do I need to enable some other source to get it?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out /etc/apt/sources.list was still referring to *precise* when it should be referring to *quantal*. Dunno how that happened, but copying /etc/apt/sources.list from another machine did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Install it in software center? It's there. I searched for it in [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=nethack-qt&op=), so it should be avalible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope, it's not there. I see it on another machine which has the same Ubuntu version but a subset of the package sources, so this is really puzzling